# How can I ensure YSlow run automatically when firefox is started?

Tags: yslow, browser-automation

It seems a dumb question: I just have to set *extensions.yslow.autorun* to **true**, then everything is supposed to work perfectly. But it's not.

When I run the bash script:

```
URLS=(http://www.google.com http://www.yahoo.com)
for link in "${URLS[@]}";
do
    firefox -P YSlow -no-remote $link &
    echo $link
    PID=$!
    sleep 20
    kill $PID
done
```

YSlow doesn't run unless I manually click the YSlow button.

Well, how can I ensure that YSlow does run everytime firefox is started? Anybody have an idea?

---

Why I want to do this:
I want to monitor several URLs' performance. And a report needs to be written every week, so it would be nice to automate this task.

I did it according to this post:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/exceptional-performance/message/822

It's frustrating that it doesn't work out when it's supposed to do.

## EDIT:

Someone having experience with **showslow** might help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Tools -> Add ons -> Yslow -> Options -> "Automatically run yslow when page finishes loading"**

Answer (score 1):

You note that

> But when I restart firefox, the process repeats. So I'm not able to automate.

Is the preference  `extensions.yslow.autorun`  being saved to your YSlow profile or the default profile? Start up the browser with `-P YSlow` and check the value of this preference in `about:config`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Enabling YSlow Autorun]

Comment: This doesn't work. I had this option chosen, but when firefox is started, yslow won't run unless I manually click yslow button. And after that, it can run automatically. But when I restart firefox, the process repeats. So I'm not able to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to make yslow autorun when the page once loaded:

First, you might have firebug installed on your firefox, and have your firebug "On for All Web Pages", and you can check the snapshot below (Sorry for the inconvenience, because I cannot upload the image because of my low reputation):

[image]

Second, you should turn autorun 'on' for yslow.

In a word, you also have to have your Firebug on all pages and autoron on for Yslow.

I am using Firefox v15.0, Yslow: 3.1.4, Firebug: 1.10.2